# What are all these missing CiviCRM CSS and jQuery files?

Tags: drupal, css

I am not sure how to ask this question or what I did to cause it, but I'll give it a shot. There seem to be several CSS files and jquery plugins that are trying to load on my Drupal 7.50 site that are broken links. I can't figure out what they are and why they are trying to load. I have recently upgraded from CiviCRM 4.3.8 to 4.7.15 and wonder if they are left-over remnants of the old version or what. All I know is that they do not exist.

Can I get rid of the safely and if so, how? Thanks!

```
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/css/deprecate.css
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/css/extras.css
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/css/extras.css?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/js/jquery/jquery.crmasmselect.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/js/rest.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/css/jquery.autocomplete.css?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/css/menu.css?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/css/token-input-facebook.css?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.css?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.0/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/DataTables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.FormNavigate.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.autocomplete.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.chainedSelects.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.jeditable.mini.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.menu.pack.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.mousewheel.pack.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.textarearesizer.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.timeentry.pack.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.pack.js?r=nMgDb
https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js?r=nMgDb
```

Here's what happens if I visit one of the jquery plugin links directly:
[image]

Edit: I compared the css and jquery files from this list with the ones in the [master code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/master/css) and they are not part of CiviCRM 4.7.15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of those files should exist in the 4.7.15 filesystem; others shouldn't.  The question is why those files are being called at all.

Most likely, you have an "HTML Snippet" somewhere in Drupal - perhaps a "sign up for our website" block or similar.  HTML snippets really should be removed if possible - but if that's not doable, you should generate a new HTML snippet and replace the older one.  That should cause MOST of these to go away.

The other thing I'm noting is that the jQuery plugins SHOULD load, not 404.  I'd check to see what happens when you visit those links directly.  It could be an HTTPS redirection issue.

Comment: You're exactly right. Previous web developer created a block with custom code for signing up to our newsletter. It referenced every single one of the files from my list.